# sublime 2 api: list project folders

Tags: api, sublimetext2

I am writing a plugin.

What is the 'right' way to get every folder path in opened project? Should I open and parse project file myself?

What I need is 'folders' section in .*sublime-project

Answer (score 1):

looks like `view.window().folders()` is what I want